# How to gray out couple last visible items of [RecyclerView]?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I make last visible items of recycler view to have a slight different style. For example, I would like them to appear like this:

[image]

As you can see, the last 3 items are grayed out proportionally. I have searched the internet but no success. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried making those specific items a different color when you bind them?

Comment: @RyanM if i understood you correctly, no I did not because I thought there was not point in doing that. Because those last items in `RecyclerView` needs to be shown in normal colors when they are scrolled to the middle or top.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question.  I'd suggest a partially transparent gradient overlay.  It'll probably look nicer than trying to recolor them.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the size of the list you are using to populate the recyler view, this may have been set in the adapter constructor. I'll call it myList.

then in your `onBindViewHolder` something like:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
....
 if (myList.size() - position < 3) {
 holder.wordRow.setTextColor(this.mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_gray));

}
```

Where `wordRow` is a `TextView` element

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom recyclerView layout and then set the topFadingEdgeLength to 0.0. This will allow you to only give effect in the bottom, else it will be applied to the top also.

In your XML

```
    <com.example.BottomFadeEdgeRecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                android:fadingEdgeLength="180dp"
                android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical">

    </com.example.BottomFadeEdgeRecyclerView>
```

I have set the fadingEdgeLength to 180dp. You can set the desired value

And the custom view class

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class BottomFadeEdgeRecyclerView : RecyclerView {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    override fun getTopFadingEdgeStrength(): Float {
        return 0.0f
    }
}
```

you can create a custom scrollView layout and then set the topFadingEdgeLength to 0.0. This will allow you to only give effect in the bottom, else it will be applied to the top also.

You can use the scrollView to wrap your recyclerView

In the XML set your scrollView as below

```
    <com.example.BottomFadeEdgeScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                android:fadingEdgeLength="180dp"
                android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical">

           <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.example.BottomFadeEdgeScrollView>
```

I have set the fadingEdgeLength to 180dp. You can set the desired value

Here's the file in Kotlin

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.widget.ScrollView

class BottomFadeEdgeScrollView : ScrollView {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    override fun getTopFadingEdgeStrength(): Float {
        return 0.0f
    }
}
```